# CallKit: App does not have internet access on declining incoming call

Tags: ios, xcode, voip, callkit, pushkit

On iOS 13 my App received voip pushkit notification, I open with callkit incoming call screen, on press decline button I need to send to server request about call termination, but my app throws `Network request failed` which means app does not have internet access. How can I get internet access on call decline? Maybe I need some permission?

Comment: How did you implement the missed call in your app..?

Comment: @Mansur with another push notification about missed call